# MySQL - Trying to count tickets sold for an event

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables, `events` and `tickets`. The `events` table contains rows of events, and `tickets` each ticket sold.

For example,

```
events
------
id name  capacity
1  Test  10
2  Test2 20
3  Test3 15

tickets
-------
id event_id customer_id
1  1        (value here doesn't matter)
2  1
3  3
4  1
5  3
```

So I can see that 3 tickets to event #1 have been sold, 0 tickets to event #2, and 2 tickets to event #3 have been sold.

I'm trying to create a query that selects all the events, plus a column `available` which is the events capacity less the count of tickets sold.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
events.id,
events.name,
events.capacity,
events.capacity - COUNT(tickets.id) AS available
FROM
events
INNER JOIN tickets ON events.id = tickets.event_id
```

However, this doesn't return any events where tickets havn't yet been sold. I thought it might be the type of join, but I tried various ones with no success.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, just change the `inner join` to a `left join`:

```
SELECT  events.id,
,       events.name
,       events.capacity
,       events.capacity - COUNT(tickets.id) AS available
FROM    events
LEFT JOIN 
        tickets 
ON      events.id = tickets.event_id
group by
        events.id,
,       events.name
,       events.capacity
```

Even though MySQL does not require it, it's good practice to list all non-aggregated columns explicitly in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Did try a left join, but I missed the group by part, which when added made it work.

Comment: @Andomar do you actually write your code like that with a wide looking space??? That spans a half line???

Comment: @Yunfei Chen: copied the style from Quassnoi like 10 years ago, it’s awesome

Answer (score 0):

It should be the join. Try a left join instead of an inner join