# MySQL Count from another table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building upon a solution I developed a while ago - ticket booking. I now need to add a feature to allow tickets to be "held" during purchasing to make them appear as sold to another customer coming to the site (preventing double-booking).

Details on the original tables are in my previous question, [MySQL - Trying to count tickets sold for an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777108/mysql-trying-to-count-tickets-sold-for-an-event). The `tickets` table now has a `held_until` DateTime value, and a `paid` tinyint (bool) value.

I need the `events.capacity - COUNT(tickets.id) AS available` to now only count those tickets which either:

- Have a `paid` value of 1
- Have a `paid` value of 0 and `held_until > now()`

I've tried adding `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses, but these prevent events where no tickets have been sold from showing. I also had a play around with nested queries but didn't get anywhere with that either...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Specifics, please, including table definition (relevant columns only) and the query SQL. Otherwise, this will probably get closed as "not a question".  You might want to re-read the [FAQ] and [Ask] (you _have_ read them, haven't you?)

Comment: OMG Ponies, I tried adding code to select only the 'taken' tickets, but was putting it in the wrong part of the query.

Comment: Jim Garrison, I thought it'd be better to not duplicate from a related question. Point taken though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify Andomar's suggested query (in the other topic) as below :

change

```
ON events.id = tickets.event_id
```

to

```
ON ( events.id = tickets.event_id AND ( tickets.paid = 1 OR tickets.held_until > now() )
```

Even if all the required information can be found in your other topic, it would probably have been a good idea to repeat some relevant details here.

Comment: I'd been putting that condition in the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses, rather than in the join, which was causing the problem. Thanks for showing that!

Comment: When you (the parser) gets to the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, consider the `JOIN` has already been performed. Glad I could help.